# Writing android app using Python and Opencv

Tags: python, android, opencv, virtual-reality

I wanted to write android app using python as I am more familiar with this language than android studio. I have come across ways to write android apps using Beeware but I found others having difficulty using opencv with beeware and deploying it on a phone which does not work. I wanted to know if there are ways to write an app using python and opencv which can be deployed on a phone? In particular, I want to use opencv to detect aruko markers and deploy this on the phone.

Comment: Just FYI as I haven't tried it: https://github.com/RivoLink/Aruco-Android and do look at the [open/closed issues](https://github.com/RivoLink/Aruco-Android/issues?q=is%3Aissue) for needed workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `PySide` is what you need, or `PyOtherSide` : https://thp.io/2011/pyotherside/
It requires a little `Qt` knowledge, but you can follow the guides and you will be safe.